# Array of pointers to pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to have an array of objects that I can pass as arguments to other objects.

Let's say, I need to have an array of People objects, and I need to pass them as arguments to Group objects. Then I need to replace a "People" object somewhere in the code, and all groups that contained the previous "People", now use the new "People" object.

Eg.:

```
People** peoples[100];
Group* groups[10];

peoples[0] = new Male();
peoples[0]->SetHeight(190);
peoples[1] = new Male();
peoples[1]->SetHeight(191);
peoples[2] = new Male();
peoples[2]->SetHeight(192);
peoples[3] = new Male();
peoples[3]->SetHeight(193);
peoples[4] = new Male();
peoples[4]->SetHeight(194);

groups[0] = new Group();
groups[0]->SetMembers(peoples[0], peoples[1], peoples[2]);
groups[1] = new Group();
groups[1]->SetMembers(peoples[0], peoples[3], peoples[4]);

delete peoples[0];
peoples[0] = new Female();
peoples[0]->SetHeight(170);
```

(btw: Male and Female inherits People)

The goal is that at the end, groups 0 and 1 have the "Female height 170" object as first member instead of the initial "Male height 190" object.
As an evidence, the place in the program where the "peoples[0]" object is deleted and replaced by the Female object doesn't know which groups do contain it, so I think pointers is the right way to go.

But, "peoples" is an array of pointers to pointers.

How do I instanciate the intermediary pointer ?

Should be something like:

```
Pointer p = new Pointer();
peoples[0] = p;
Male* m = new Male();
p.address = f;
```

then

```
Female* f = new Female();
delete peoples[0].address;
peoples[0].address = f;
```

For sure it's not the right code, I'm a bit stuck on how to achieve this.

Comment: can you explain more why you think you need an array of pointers to pointers? I am pretty sure that you don't but I don't know what else to propose. Some code that uses that array and illustrates what you currently describe in text would maybe help

Comment: Rather sounds like the correct way to do this is to create a default constructor taking height as a parameter and is defined in the base class. Then you can create arrays of whatever objects that make sense and point at different arrays if needed.

Comment: the actual program is actually huge, difficult to copy/past, and I was using an array of pointers (Poeple* poeples[100];), and crashed when I deleted the first object and set peoples[0] = new Female(); as groups[0] and [1] had a reference to the deleted object.

Comment: @Lundin, the height is not the issue, my problem is I need to replace an object with a whole different object, here a Male by a Female, could be replacing a House by a Skyscrapper, whatever!

Comment: I could create a "PeopleContainer" object but I thought pointer to pointer would be more efficient.

Comment: @Sierramike From a program design point of view, that doesn't make much sense. You should rather have a class `Human` with a member `gender`.

Comment: "Male by a Female, could be replacing a House by a Skyscrapper," smells like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). An array of pointers to pointers to object isn't quite the right way to store objects of arbitrary types. There are ways, but in your question you are not talking about your actual problem, rather about what you think is the solution (and an array of pointers to pointers is very likely not the solution)

Comment: @Lundin, don't try to guess what the program does, I simplified the code to be easy to ask the question. The actual program is handling Analog and Digital outputs, each behaving completely differently, having a member "Type" and then every method containing "if (Type == Analog) then { do a whole bunch of things with 30 variables } else { do a whole different bunch of things with 10 different variables } would be against object model programming.

Comment: If `peoples` is an array of pointers to pointers and is made of `Male`s and `Female`s, the latter should be pointers to objects. `peoples[0] = new Female();` creates a new pointer (`Female` is a pointer), but `Female` does not point to anything.  You should define a ``Female = new FemaleObject;` or something like that.

Comment: @Sierramike In most applications, it doesn't make sense to mix analog and digital outputs in the first place. (That's the kind of programs I write every day.) If you for some reason unknown feel that _must_ mix them, then you would use polymorphism by calling a function output or some such. But the vast majority of of such cases of inheritance turn out to be over-engineered metaprogramming crap when deployed in the real world. Stick to the KISS principle. Preferably avoid the whole C++ language for systems actually handling analog/digital outputs.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for your hints, but it MUST be mixed in my case. I can guarantee the C++ language saves me a lot of headaches in my program, where outputs can be reconfigured at runtime by the end user, and the whole configuration must be saved to disk and read when the device restarts. I end up using encapsulation, works like a charm, just thought pointers to pointers would be a more efficient way to achieve it.

Comment: @Sierramike if your pointers aren't unique, you have to consider this: have a manger, a factory that cretes your objects, stores as shared_ptr in its pool, returns you weak_ptrs. You operated with array of weak_ptrs. If factory deleter would destroy an object from pool, all weak_ptrs will null-ify automatically. No need in three-star code (in your code, literally if would require ***)

Answer (score 0):

Store the pointer to the pointer-pointer of People in your Groups instead.

```
typedef struct Group {
    People ***members;
    ...
} Group;

...

groups[0] = new Group();
groups[0]->SetMembers(&peoples[0], &peoples[1], &peoples[2]);
```

This may get pretty messy ahead. It may be tempting at first, but I strongly recommend you to find an alternative way of doing what you want.

Comment: Smells like a solution looking for a problem to solve. But hey, it got three stars...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using encapsulation for the intermediary object :

```
class PeopleContainer
{
  public:
    PeopleContainer() {}
    PeopleContainer(People* myPeople) { ptr = myPeople; }
    People* ptr;
};
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Doesn't do much but sugaring the syntax... at this stage I would have considered array of smart pointers (uniwue_ptr or shared_ptr depending on use case) as element of array... supports polymorphism and such.